# XSLT renaming attribute value according to hard coded map

Tags: attributes, rename, xslt-2.0

I'm really new at this XSLT and fail to understand from XSLT questions how to do the below.

I have conversion map for VOCABULARY values :

```
French -> france
Spenish -> Spain
```

and couple more (I can have them inside the xslt file itself it's not too much)

How can I convert value of attribute with a equal condition according to this pre-defined map?

```
...
    <Languages>
        <LANGUAGE>French</LANGUAGE>
        <VOCABULARY>French</VOCABULARY>
    </Languages>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the mapping in an XML format

```xml
<xsl:variable name="conversionRules">
  <rule from="French" to="France" />
  <rule from="Spanish" to="Spain" />
</xsl:variable>
```

and define a key

```xml
<xsl:key name="conversionKey" match="rule" use="@from" />
```

then in XSLT 2.0 you can efficiently look items up in this mapping using

```
key('conversionKey', value, $conversionRules)/@to
```

For example

```xml
<xsl:template match="VOCABULARY">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('conversionKey', ., $conversionRules)/@to" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If you're doing this repeatedly in different places in your stylesheet it might be worth defining a function

```xml
<xsl:function name="local:lang-to-country" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="lang" as="xs:string" />
  <xsl:sequence select="key('conversionKey', $lang, $conversionRules)/@to" />
</xsl:function>
```

(adding the relevant `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` and `xmlns:local="urn:local"` declarations to the `xsl:stylesheet`) and then you can do the conversion with simply `local:lang-to-country(.)`

Comment: you need to use the function parameter i.e. `<xsl:sequence select="key('conversionKey', $lang, $conversionRules)/@to" />`.